# VBA Macro: Auto-filling date in following column once a value is added, independently accross same row

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to preface my question with the fact that I am not a programmer, I know very little to nothing about coding and this may be very easy.

I am a mortgage loan officer and am trying to streamline my application roster. I have a Macro that I got from this life saving site but I would like to understand how I can add some utility. I have columns at the end of my table for "Reviewed," "Sold," and "dead." I have a conditional formatting set when a "y" is added to any of the columns it auto-fills that row with a corresponding color.

When I add that "y," I would also like the following column to add the date the "y" was added.

Right now I am using the following sub to auto-populate the date after the name. How can I amend it to also add the date column P if I add a y to column O, date to column R if I add a "y" to column Q and a date to column T if I add a "y" to column S.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, Inte As Range, r As Range
    Set A = Range("A:A")
    Set Inte = Intersect(A, Target)
    If Inte Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each r In Inte
            If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
               r.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            End If
        Next r
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Column Index` nicely here check if the `Target` is in one of your key columns.

The indexes are `A=1`, `O=15`, `Q=17`, & `S=19`. Since you always want to insert the date to right, your `Offset(0, 1)` will work for all cases. The last step is to just check if the cell that was changed is `y`

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim MyCell As Range

For Each MyCell In Target
    Select Case Target.Column
        Case 1, 15, 17, 19
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                If Target = "y" Then Target.Offset(, 1) = Date
            Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Select
Next MyCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure what the rest of your code is supposed to be doing, so here's the relevant part to what you're trying to do. The `Target` variable that is being passed to the function is the cell that changed. This is set for you already.

Next you have to see what column was edited by checking `Target.column` if it's in columns 15, 17, or 19 (O, Q, or S), then you know you're in the correct column. Next, you need to check if what you just entered is a 'y'. This example presumes that you're only using lowercase ys.

Finally, you can add 1 to the `Target` column and set that value equal to the date.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 15 Or Target.Column = 17 Or Target.Column = 19 Then
        If Target.Value = "y" Then
            Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1) = Date
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: This will crash excel since you did not toggle off events

Comment: Does not appear to be crashing my excel while I test it.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. What is actually happening is your macro runs again when you use your line `Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column +1) = Date` since it changes a cell. Your macro then recognizes that the changed cell is not one of the key columns. Either way, you should toggle off events to stop the macro from unnecessarily being called multiple times.

Comment: Every time a target column is changed, your macro will run two times. The first will make the change, and the second will not.

Comment: You are correct that it fire twice, and thanks for the reminder about the ability to disable events. But the example does not run away and crash anything. The second iteration is not going to slow down the user's computer. You could make an argument about the effect on a large sheet, but the macro is not looping over a large range.